# Dropzone not working with form elements

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Hi i have this kind of form:

```
    <form role="form" method="post" action="pridat_nehn.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Časť mesta / obce</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="city_part" placeholder="Zadajte časť mesta alebo obce.">
         <button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary">Pridať nehnuteľnosť</button>
    </form>
```

And I javascript:

```
     Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

     Dropzone.options.addProperty = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

        url: "pridat_nehn.php", 
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 15,
        maxFiles: 15,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
        dictDefaultMessage: "Vložte obrázky.",


      // The setting up of the dropzone
      init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

         $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
        );
      }
     }
```

But I cannot click dropzone area and select files. It does nothing. I can just submit form with element data. But when I comment out

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

I can select pictures, but clicking on submit does nothing.

What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not invoked because you didn't add `id="add-propert"` to your form which is later used to attribute your customized Dropzone to the given element.